# How enable Intellisense for Javascript AMD modules in VSCode

Tags: javascript, requirejs, intellisense, amd, visual-studio-code

According to [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages#_javascript)

> IntelliSense across CommonJS and AMD modules inside your project
>   folders is enabled by understanding your code.

Does anyone have more information about how to get this to work? I've tried adding the following to my workspace settings.json file, but no joy.

```
"javascript.validate.module": "amd"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to set "javascript.validate.baseUrl" setting.

*// Allows to configure the base url that is used to resolve module references (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-baseUrl). This options applies only to projects that use the asynchronous module definition ("module": "amd")*.

```
"javascript.validate.baseUrl": "",
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I couldn't get it to work though. My Code workspace is such that my modules, and the require.js main.js file are contained in app/js. I've tried setting the baseUrl setting to app/js, app/js/, and app/js/main.js, but no completion.

Comment: Where do I put this line of configuration? What file?